# How can I apply Gradle plugin from directly GitHub repo

Tags: github, gradle, gradle-plugin

I tried to apply `plugin` directly from `GitHub` repo e.g. as given below

`apply from 'https://github.com/gradle/gradle-hello-world-plugin'` but on running

`./gradlew codeLines`

It gives me error as

```
* Where:
Script 'https://github.com/SurpSG/code-lines-counter-gradle-plugin' line: 7

* What went wrong:
Could not compile script 'https://github.com/SurpSG/code-lines-counter-gradle-plugin'.
> startup failed:
  script 'https://github.com/SurpSG/code-lines-counter-gradle-plugin': 7: unexpected token: < @ line 7, column 1.
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     ^
```

How can I directly `apply plugin` from remote git repo?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is automatically published to [jitpack](https://jitpack.io/#SurpSG/code-lines-counter-gradle-plugin).

You could apply the plugin in the next way:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.SurpSG:code-lines-counter-gradle-plugin:0.0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.code-lines'
```

Note! [code-lines-counter-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/SurpSG/code-lines-counter-gradle-plugin) is sample project created as a part of [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/the-complete-custom-gradle-plugin-building-tutoria).
I don't recommend to use it because it far from production ready

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. The closest think you can do is clone the plugin, build it and point to it

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        [...]
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath files('relative/path/to/gradle-hello-world-plugin.jar')
    }
}

apply plugin: org.gradle.plugin.HelloWorldPlugin
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35472676/2003986