# How to use gradle plugin globally from GitHub repository?

Tags: android, gradle, plugins, repository

I trying to access the GitHub repository like below

```
pluginManagement{
repositories {
    github {
        url "https://github.com/plugin"
    }
}
```

}

instead of referring to the plugin locally. Is there any way to do it? I was looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66207017/how-can-i-apply-gradle-plugin-from-directly-github-repo) here someone mentioned about [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/#SurpSG/code-lines-counter-gradle-plugin) but this is paid service.